# Receive Undefined in Ajax success/complete function

Tags: ajax, json

I am using Jquery 1.11.1. My code is as below and I receive "undefined" in response to ajax call. Can anyone please help me to find the solution?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtSearch").keyup(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var x = $("#txtSearch").val();
       // alert(x);
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Search","OfficeLocation")',
            dataType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({"Location":x}),
           // dataType: "json",

           complete: function (data) {

                var table = "<table class='table'>";
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    table += "<tr><td>" + value.Name + "</td></tr>"; 
                });
                table += "</table>";
                alert(table);
                $("#myData").html(table);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And the related Controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(string Location)
    {
        var LocationViewModel = new List<OfficeAssignment>();
        LocationViewModel = db.OfficeAssignments.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(Location)).ToList();
        return Json(LocationViewModel,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

When I use success instead of complete, it does not hit the success function!

Answer (score 0):

That is because complete runs *after* the success and error callbacks. I think you're getting an error, so try to catch that and see what it receives.

How is the url '@Url.Action("Search","OfficeLocation")' actually computed in javascript? It doesn't seem a valid url to me.

Comment: It seems the URL works and send the value to the controller but does not get back the json result to the complete/success function.I see that the LocationViewModel includes the correct number of values! So, what else may cause the problem?!

Comment: Try to add an 'error' handler and debug from there. Or else add a try-catch serverside. Maybe a serverside error occured. There's always a response if the server returns something. Another thing is to inspect the POST request to the server and see what it returns in the developer tools of your browser.

Comment: I got [object][object]. I tried ways to read the properties Name of this value but still shows the like object.